# Microsoft WSL make issue

Tags: makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to build a project in WSL. the same project compiles in ubuntu18.04 VM, but not in WSL ubuntu18.04. The issue I see is that make is unable to include the MakefileCommom in the makefile.
The makefile contents are as below:

```
-include ~/MakefileCommon
RM := rm -rf
all:
    $(MAKE) -f ./$(MAKEFILE_TARGET) $@
clean:  
    $(MAKE) -f ./$(MAKEFILE_TARGET) $@
image:
    $(MAKE) -f ./$(MAKEFILE_TARGET) $@
uninstall:
    $(MAKE) -f ./$(MAKEFILE_TARGET) $@

-include ../makefile.targets
```

The command I am using is:

```
make -C builds clean all
```

The error I get is:

```
make -f ./ clean
make[1]: *** ./: Is a directory.  Stop.
```

Thus I see, $(MAKEFILE_TARGET) is note getting imported. the import statements are in MakefileCommon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tilde `~` in a pathname is a magical character that expands to the user's home directory on a POSIX system.  I have no idea what it expands to in Windows, but my guess is it's not what you expected.  Try putting a real path here instead of using `~`.  Also you can run `make -d` and examine the output to see what pathname it's using for `MakefileCommon`.

Comment: I did, it also showed the same issue. I even used a . Instead of a ~. But still the same issue

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of running make with the `-d` option and looking through the output for `MakefileCommon` to see what the path it's looking for is?  Does that path exist?  Does it set the `MAKEFILE_TARGET` variable?  Maybe you should try removing the `-include` and just using `include` for `MakefileCommon` instead so it will fail if that file doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried that, I get error `file does not exist`. if I use the `~` then it searches the `/home/yash/MakefileCommon` file, which is the wrong path. Hence, not sure why it is not searching the builds directory in `/home/yash/Project/builds` where the file is actually located. Also in windows when I do `ls` I don't see the `.` and the `..` in the list. So I am assuming windows just ignores the `.` which is why it is not able to find `./Makefilecommon` as it is being changed to `/MakefileCommon`.

Comment: I think you might be confused.  The tilde character always stands for the user's home directory (this is true on POSIX systems as well).  So `~/MakefileCommon` will always mean the file `MakefileCommon` in the user's home directory, which is exactly what make is looking for above.  If you want to look for `MakefileCommon` in some other directory you can't use `~`.  In particular `~` does _not_ mean the current directory (unless the current directory is the user's home directory.  To look for a file in the current directory you use just `include MakefileCommon` or `include ./MakefileCommon`.

Comment: As for `ls` not showing `.` or `..`, that's normal: files and directories that start with the `.` character are "hidden" and `ls` won't show them by default.  That's true on POSIX systems as well.  If you want to see all the files including hidden files, use the `-a` option: `ls -a` then you'll see them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am not very well versed with linux systems. I really appreciate your comments.